# How to export an editable table in crystal reports to word document using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports-2008, .doc

The table which I am trying to export is imported in Crystal Reports from a SQL database in Visual Studio 2008 where I am making a web application with C#. I am trying to export it to a word document but to keep the table formatting which I can later on edit in MS WORD. However, all i get is a bunch of text boxes.

I tried exporting it as an excel document and then copying to word, and that worked, but I need to be able to do that solely through C# code.

So the question is: Is there a better way to directly have an editable table in word document exported from crystal reports, or is there a solution how to copy an excel table in word but only doing so by c# code?

I really appreciate any help! I'm googling for a couple of days and I still haven't found a proper solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to insert the Excel document to Word and then save it. The minor problem with just tha data paths needs a little tweaking, but besides that it works :)

private void ConvertExcelToWordAndAutoSave()
        {

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
       //TT Excel.Range range;



        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = DateTime.Now;

            // open excel 
            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            //Change THE LOCATION!
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Student\\Desktop\\ExportFiles\\Excel.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet=(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;




            // open word 
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            //Start Word and create a new document.
            Word._Application oWord;
            Word._Document oDoc;

            oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);



            Word.Paragraph oPara1;
            oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
            oPara1.Range.Text = "Snimeno na:" + " " + dt+"\n";
            oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;    //24 pt spacing after paragraph.
            oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();




            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "N49").Copy(Missing.Value);

            oWord.Selection.Paste();

            oWord.Selection.TypeParagraph();
           //The textBox is for the name of the new Word document
            if (TextBox1.Text == "")
                TextBox1.Text = "Document1";
         object fileName = @"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Student\\Desktop\\ExportFiles\\"+TextBox1.Text+".docx"; 

            oDoc.SaveAs(ref fileName,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```